# Android, menu option with items

Tags: android, android-menu

I have create a menu with couple options, but I want to get a separate page when I click on them in `MainActivity`. As in: if I click on `Movies`, I would have other page showing lists of movies and so on.

Which functions should I call for that?

```
package com.example.popupmenu.popupmenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}

   public void showPopUp(View v){

    PopupMenu popup=new PopupMenu(this,v);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu. main_menu, popup.getMenu() );
             popup.show();
}


     @Override
     public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

       switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.Movies:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "movies Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.MeloDramas:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Melodramas Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.Songs:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Songs Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
         default:
            return false;
    }
    //return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Your menu Click do this thing to `StartActivity`.

```
 case R.id.Movies:
       Intent launchNewIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
       startActivity(launchNewIntent);
       return true;
```

this will open new Activity.

Comment: Didn't work. I don't have 2nd activity, I want to call it from main Activity itself

Comment: If you want to call itself then use `Intent launchNewIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Create a movie list activity. Then in your menuitemclick function in MainActivity, call intent to MovieActivity. 
For eg;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MovieActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new activity by using `startActivity`. To learn more about starting activities please visit [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) link.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MovieActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you didn't called `showPopUp(View v)` you need to call that for inflating menu. and if you want regular menu then why you are using popup menu.. just use this for inflating menu...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.Movies) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SplashScreen.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.MeloDramas) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,melodramas.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In this case you don't need to call any method just put these two method..

Answer (score 0):

i would advise you to use fragments based on MenuItem selected
 public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)